# How to set id in PHP with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php

Here is my PHP code:

```
 <?php foreach ($departement as $departement){ ?>
 <a href="#" data-id="<?php echo $departement['departement_id'];?>" 
    id="<?php echo $departement['departement_id'];?>" onClick="reply_click(this.id)" 
    class="btn btn-lg btn-primary quick-link-btn nextBtn">
    <?php echo $departement['departement_name'];?>                    
 </a>
 <?php } ?>
```

Here is my JS code

```
 function reply_click(clicked_id) {
      //alert(clicked_id);
      var x = document.getElementsByClassName("dept_id");
      x[0].innerHTML = clicked_id;
 }
```

How to display id into method?

```
  $departement_id = '<p class="dept_id"></p>';     
  $orderByDepartement = $this->HRmodels->listHRByDept($departement_id);
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing your code... though you appear to have omitted your actual **question**.

Comment: Have you used the browser inspection to ensure the `id` are what you expect them to be? also have you checked the browser console for errors?

Comment: Your foreach loop seems incorrect. Check `$departement as $departement`.